# Printing a string in a Mathematica script

Tags: output-formatting, scripting

Here's a simple script saved in the file `hello`

```
#!/usr/local/bin/MathematicaScript -script
Print["Hello world"]
```

I can then run this file using `math -script hello` or, 
if the file is set to be executable, `./hello`.
In Windows or OSX, run `MathKernel -script hello`

It prints

> "Hello world"

to the terminal.

How can I change this so it does not print the quotation marks?

Comment: I was using `Print` for outputting warnings in [this superuser question](http://superuser.com/q/381807/45585). Is there a better way of printing warnings to the terminal?

Comment: Have a look at `Message`, which seems to be the usual way to handle warnings in Mathematica (I think).

Comment: @David: You're right, but then I need to define a new message, which seemed overkill for a short script (`Messages[General]` does not contain an appropriate message for me to use).

Comment: not that this matters, but `./hello` should also work on OS X if the script is executable (and you have the right shebang)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Another option is to set `FormatType -> OutputForm` on the `$Output` stream:

```
SetOptions[ $Output, FormatType -> OutputForm ];
Print["Hello"];
```

Or call OutputForm on the string itself:

```
Print[ OutputForm["Hello"] ];
```

Comment: +1 That's the solution I came up with after noticing the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathematicaScripts.html) say that for Mathematica scripts, all output is in `InputForm`. (This was after posting the question)

Answer (score 12):

[`WriteString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WriteString.html) is the function you're looking for. It takes two parameters, the first one being the stream you want to write to (in your case standard output, [`$Output`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24Output.html)), the second argument is what you want to print.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/MathematicaScript -script
WriteString[$Output, "Hello World!\n"]
```

> ```
> david@thinkpad:~/temp$ ./asdf
> Hello World!
> ```

If you need more general information about streams in Mathematica [have a look at the corresponding help page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StreamsAndLowLevelInputAndOutput.html).

Comment: +1 Thanks David. I'd never used `WriteString` before.