# Formatting and printing lists with Mathematica scripts

Tags: output-formatting, scripting

I'm just starting out with *Mathematica* and I'm using `MathematicaScript` rather than the GUI. However, I'm having trouble formatting a list when printing it.

Suppose I have a list and I want to print it using [`Column`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Column.html):

```
list = {a, b, c};
Print[Column[list]];
```

Calling this outputs `Column[{a, b, c}]` rather than

```
a
b
c
```

I suspect that this is because I'm running *Mathematica* in script mode. Is there anything I can do to display a list like this? How can I verify what the cause of my problem is from the documentation (I'm having trouble running the GUI)? The documentation doesn't say anything about `Column` only working in GUI mode.

I assume that the answer to getting a list (if there is one) to display as a column will explain how to do the same for a grid with 2D lists.

Comment: On second thoughts, I'd rather it not be closed as a duplicate. Pls ignore the vtc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can force the `Column` to display correctly in text-only script mode by passing it explicitly to `OutputForm`. For example:

```
#!/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathematicaScript -script
list = {a, b, c};
Print[Column[list] // OutputForm];
```

gives the output you expect:

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: Or, as mentioned [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/651), execute `SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> OutputForm];` before anything else...

Comment: Yes, `OutputForm` is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks to both of you! (I wish I could think of looking for something like `OutputForm` on my own...)

Comment: This does not work for me. It just prints `OutputForm[Column[{a, b, c}]]`(I call scripts with `MathKernel -script`)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by F'x does not work for me ("12.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"). The following does work:
Simply include

```
SetOptions[ $Output, FormatType -> OutputForm ];
```

at the start of your script so that all output gets displayed in `OutputForm`. (See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/651/45020)