# how to write string to file without Quotation mark

Tags: export

I am trying to Write String to file, something like this:

```
Write["test.txt", "This is a test"];
```

when I opened the file I found that the string was written with the Quotation mark " like this:

"This is a test"

how can I write only the string text?

**Note:** "This is a test" is part of matrix and I can't manually type it like this:

```
Write["test.txt", This is a test];
```

Comment: Try `Export` instead of `Write`.

Comment: Does not help because Export overwrite the file. I am using continues writing to the file using OpenAppend

Comment: Related: [(648)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/648),
[(5585)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5585),
[(41047)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41047)

Comment: Can't you use `Export["test.txt","This is a test","Text"]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

one way:

```
 SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
 fileName = "test.txt";
 file = OpenWrite[fileName, PageWidth -> Infinity];
 WriteString[file,"this is a string which will show up without the quotes"];
 Close[file]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To open for append and lines:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
fileName = "AAA.txt";
file = OpenAppend[fileName, PageWidth -> Infinity];
WriteString[file, "this is a string which will show up without the quotes\n"];
WriteString[file, "second line\n"];
Close[file]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**important:**  must add "\n" at the end of the string. Without it,
all string will remain on same line.

You can also in the notebook, add the new line, and will be be reflected in the file. Like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice, in the above there is no explicit "\n" there, but it was added in the notebook. The above will look like this in the text file:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One thing I want to add, the text I am writing is an element in big list. you would agree if instead of adding "\n" to the end of the text, I can add WriteString["AAA.txt", "\n"]; after what I want to write.

Comment: @Algohi First, it is `WriteString[file, "\n"]` where `file` is the file handle returned from the `OpenAppend` call. Second, yes, you can do "\n" on its own, it will go to the end of the last written string and make new line. `WriteString` does not add "\n" on its own. The user has control on that. You can write `WriteString[file,"A\nB\n"]` if you want.

Answer (score 4):

Addressing the comment, `WriteString` can take multiple arguments to write multiple expressions so you can do:

```
 WriteString[file, "string" , "\n" ]
```

which may be somewhat more convenient than concatenating the "\n" to the string.

If you want to write a list of strings adding linebreaks you can do like this:

```
 WriteString[f, 
      Sequence @@ Riffle[{"string1", "string2", "String3"}, "\n"], "\n"]
```